# Need to optimize multiple soql queries while assigning the case back to queue?

Tags: apex, trigger, email2case

Here the scenario is when ever the case is closed, am trying to clone the case and sending it back to the queue. so, Please review the below mentioned code and add your suggestions to replace multiple soql queries with any other alternatives.

**Code:**

```
trigger CloneClosedCase on EmailMessage (after insert) {
Set<ID> caseSet = new Set<ID>();
List<Case>cloneList = new List<Case>();
Map<Id, String> emailBodyMap = new Map<Id, String>{};
for (EmailMessage so : Trigger.new) {
    //if(so.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.sObjectType && so.Incoming){
      if(((String)so.parentid).startsWith('500') && so.Incoming){
        caseSet.add(so.parentid);
        emailBodyMap.put(so.ParentId, so.TextBody);
    } 
}
Map<Id,case> caseMAP = new Map<Id,case>([SELECT id,origin,subject,Policy__c,Type,Claim__c,Complainant__c,SR_Sub_Type__c,Remarks_for_pending_status__c,status,description,parentid FROM Case WHERE id in:caseSet]);  
Group ComplaintsQueue= [Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND Name = 'Inbound Complaints' Limit 1];
Group ComplaintsQueue1= [Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND Name = 'Inbound Claims' Limit 1];
Group ComplaintsQueue2= [Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND Name = 'Inbound Customer Service' Limit 1];
Group ComplaintsQueue3= [Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND Name = 'Inbound Policy Renewal' Limit 1];
for(Case c:caseMAP.values()){
    if(c.Status=='Closed') {
        system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+c.Id);
        system.debug('##############'+c.subject);
        Case cloneCase = c.clone(false,true);
        cloneCase.parentid=c.id;
        if(cloneCase.Origin=='Email - Complaints'){
        cloneCase.Ownerid=ComplaintsQueue.id;
        } else      
         if(cloneCase.Origin=='Email - Claims'){
        cloneCase.Ownerid=ComplaintsQueue1.id;
        }   else            
        if(cloneCase.Origin=='Email - Customer Service'){
        cloneCase.Ownerid=ComplaintsQueue2.id;
        }        
        else{
        cloneCase.Ownerid=ComplaintsQueue3.id;
        }
        cloneCase.Origin=c.Origin;
      //cloneCase.subject=c.subject;
        cloneCase.Policy__c=c.Policy__c;
        cloneCase.Claim__c=c.Claim__c;
        cloneCase.Type=c.Type;
        cloneCase.SR_Sub_Type__c=c.SR_Sub_Type__c;
        cloneCase.Remarks_for_pending_status__c=c.Remarks_for_pending_status__c;
        cloneCase.Status='New';
        cloneCase.Description= emailBodyMap.get(c.Id);
        cloneList.add(cloneCase);
        system.debug('*********************' +cloneList);
    }
}
try { 
    insert cloneList;      
} catch(DMLException e) {   
     System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage()); 
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace multiple lists"? I only see one `List` in your provided code. Also, why do you need to 'optimize'? What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @Derek F : Am sorry, what i mean to say is how do i reduce all the 4 soql queries and use any other alternative to get the queue details in a single query.

Comment: Could do one group query and put the results into a map

Comment: Could you please let me know in detail or with any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible approach, the first that came to mind. I am sure others on here can provide a better/cleaner one...

Use one query to add all the values you want to map:

```
List<Group> allGroups = new List<Group>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Group]);
```

Add to a Map with the developername as the Key:

```
Map<String,Group> groupMap = new Map<String,Group>();
for(Group g : allGroups){
    groupMap.put(g.DeveloperName,g);
}
```

Then when you need to get an id use the Map:

```
cloneCase.Ownerid = groupMap.get('Inbound_Complaints').Id;
```

**Note** I changed it to use the developername as this is **less** likely to be changed - the issue with this approach is you are hardcoding references to these groups. If/when they can are changed or you need to add more you need to update the code.

**EDIT**

Actually I would go one step further at least and use a static map that can be reused across the transaction - not many how many times the trigger fires in the same transaction it only use one query:

```
public static map<String, Group> groupMap{
    get{
        if(groupMap== null){
            List<Group> allGroups = new List<Group>([SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Group]);
            for(Group g : allGroups){
                groupMap.put(g.DeveloperName,g);
            }
        }
        return groupMap;      
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you...!! It really helped. But for the assignment step i have id cloneCase.Ownerid = groupMap.get('Inbound_Complaints').id;

Comment: You are correct - I've updated the answer.